# Matlab Seeded Region Growing

Tags: matlab

I have used the following code from the matlab central website in my project to perform seeded region growing. This works perfectly but I am struggling to understand exactly what the code is doing in some places. I have contacted the author but have had no reply. Would anyone be able to provide me with some explanations ?

```
function Phi = segCroissRegion(tolerance,Igray,x,y)
if(x == 0 || y == 0)
    imshow(Igray,[0 255]);
    [x,y] = ginput(1);
end
Phi = false(size(Igray,1),size(Igray,2));
ref = true(size(Igray,1),size(Igray,2));
PhiOld = Phi;
Phi(uint8(x),uint8(y)) = 1;
while(sum(Phi(:)) ~= sum(PhiOld(:)))
    PhiOld = Phi;
    segm_val = Igray(Phi);
    meanSeg = mean(segm_val);
    posVoisinsPhi = imdilate(Phi,strel('disk',1,0)) - Phi;
    voisins = find(posVoisinsPhi);
    valeursVoisins = Igray(voisins);
    Phi(voisins(valeursVoisins > meanSeg - tolerance & valeursVoisins < meanSeg + tolerance)) = 1;
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added some comments in your code :

```
function Phi = segCroissRegion(tolerance,Igray,x,y)

% If there's no point, select one from image

if(x == 0 || y == 0)
    imshow(Igray,[0 255]);
    [x,y] = ginput(1);
end

%Create seed with by adding point in black image

Phi = false(size(Igray,1),size(Igray,2));
ref = true(size(Igray,1),size(Igray,2));
PhiOld = Phi;
Phi(uint8(x),uint8(y)) = 1;
while(sum(Phi(:)) ~= sum(PhiOld(:)))
    PhiOld = Phi;
% Evaluate image intensity at seed/line points
    segm_val = Igray(Phi);
% Calculate mean intensity at seed/line points
    meanSeg = mean(segm_val);
% Grow seed 1 pixel, and remove previous seed (so you'll get only new pixel perimeter)
    posVoisinsPhi = imdilate(Phi,strel('disk',1,0)) - Phi;
% Evaluate image intensity over the new perimeter
    voisins = find(posVoisinsPhi);
    valeursVoisins = Igray(voisins);
% If image intensity over new perimeter is greater than the mean intensity of previous perimeter (minus tolerance), than this perimeter is part of the segmented object
    Phi(voisins(valeursVoisins > meanSeg - tolerance & valeursVoisins < meanSeg + tolerance)) = 1;
% Repeat while there's new pixel in seed, stop if no new pixel were added
end
```